# Add Multiple json objects to a json on Robotframework

Tags: json, robotframework

[edit a JSON file in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283542/edit-a-json-file-in-robot-framework/58881145#58881145)

assume the same problem above but if I need to add multiple objects and it should be passed as a variable. How can we do this?

```
json objects(key value pair)

{
"drive": 1,
"case_ids": [1419]
}


*** Settings ***
Documentation    Library with keywords
Library          Collections
Library          DateTime
Library          OperatingSystem
Library          JSONLibrary


Robot file
    *** Keywords ***
    ################################## New Functions Introduced       #########################################
    Add KeyValue To Json
    [Arguments]  ${config_file}  ${key}  ${value}  ${address}=$

    ${json_obj}=    Load JSON From File  ${config_file}
    ${object_to_add}=    Create Dictionary  ${key}=${value}
    ${json_obj}=    Add Object To Json  ${json_obj}  ${address}  ${object_to_add}

    [return]  ${json_obj}
```

I believe we can't make key and value to a single variable last time I checked it dint work.

any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept it as simple as this. I just have to call the keyword again to add them into an object. Reuse the same keyword to achieve both.

```
Add KeyValue To JsonFile and JsonObject
    [Arguments]  ${key}  ${value}  ${config_file}=None  ${json_arg}=None  ${address}=$
    ${json_obj} =  Run Keyword If  '${config_file}' != 'None'    Load JSON From File  ${config_file}
    ${object_to_add}=    Create Dictionary  ${key}=${value}
    ${json_obj}=    Add Object To Json  ${json_obj}  ${address}  ${object_to_add}
    Return From Keyword If    ${json_obj} is not ${None}    ${json_obj}

    ${json_obj}=  Run Keyword    Create Dictionary
    ${json_obj}=    Add Object To Json  ${json_arg}  ${address}  ${object_to_add}
    Log    ${json_obj}
    [return]  ${json_obj}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the comments(rightly so), do not spend time in figuring something out like in a "language", although it is perfectly fine to do so(but, it would be like designing a wheel and then testing the same- not reinventing it), Please consider installing the following module pip install robotframework-jsonlibrary and solve the problem you are facing and move on to the next one.

the example is shown below
Example Test Case

```
*** Settings ***                
Library JSONLibrary         
*** Test Cases ***              
${json_obj}=    Load JSON From File example.json        
${object_to_add}=   Create Dictionary   country=Thailand        
**${json_obj}=  Add Object To Json  ${json_obj} $..address  ${object_to_add}**
${value}=   Get Value From Json ${json_obj} $..country  
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${value[0]} Thailand        
${value_to_update}= Set Variable    Japan       
${json_obj}=    Update Value To Json    ${json_obj} $..country  ${value_to_update}
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${json_obj['country']   ${value_to_update}      
Documentation
```

Comment: I have been using the module, but let me show what I did. Its when I pass multiple json object I was confused on how to handle it.  I could see you have handled it with static objects country=Thailand being passed. But my question is say if its more than 1 json object to be passed as a variable as in the question how do we for loop the dictionary or a list and achieve this?

Comment: my question is having 2 objects being added to a json, but that's an example. How can we iterate and add all the object in the same address on the json

Comment: just re-read your questions, I understand what you mean. don't over complicate it since its not a language

Comment: you are just adding values to a single key, its getting complicated when you want to add multiple object to a single json.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Python extension for this problem.

File name must be same as the class name, otherwise Robot framework won't find the function.

Filename: JsonExtender.py

Content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class JsonExtender(object):
    def extend_json_obj(self, json_obj, key, value):
        json_obj[key]=value
        return json_obj
```

Test suite file: mytest.robot

content:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../path_to_file/JsonExtender.py

*** Test Cases ***
my test
     ${json_obj}=           Load JSON From File  ${config_file}
     ${extended_json_obj}=  Extend Json Obj      ${json_obj}        key_name    value
```

Keep in mind, this script only an example, need a small bit of adaptation, as this version will accept normal dict, not json.

Comment: Are there any other improvised way to use an existing library module to achieve this?  Is the above solution tested against the question?

Comment: Not tested, as you can see the note at the bottom. That would be your homework.

Comment: Just a side note. Robot framework is test framework, not a program language. One of the core principals "make it simple". If you need something complex, than create an external modul. That is why this is a good example. It also gives a simple example, how to create external modul.

Comment: would you be able to explain a bit more on the external module JsonExtender.py